# No getElementById for body?

Tags: javascript, dom

This question has disturbed me for a long time. Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Before, I have known that you can get the elements with a class name

```
document.body.getElementsByClassName("foo");
```

And I was so lazy, so I just copied and pasted the code to the other part to do this

```
document.body.getElementById("bar");
```

I accidentally found it won't work. I tested and it says

> TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'getElementById'

So why does it have `getElementsByClassName` and`getElementsByTagName` and all those similar methods, but only no [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)?

```
typeof document === typeof document.body   //true
```

Their types are the same, so they should have the same thing. But it does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: `typeof` is `"object"` for both which means they can be *any* kind of objects. It doesn't tell you much about the methods they have.

Comment: "Their types are the same, so they should have the same thing." No. They are both objects, but not all objects share the same properties/methods.

Comment: Recommendation, never check types in javascript to see if things are the same, iterate over the properties and check them. Because `typeof document === typeof document.body === typeof null === typeof [] === "object"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple elements with the same class name so narrowing down the search to start with a specific node make sense.

It doesn't make sense with id because it it should be unique.

You can have only one `id` in the `document`, this why `getElementById` is a method of `document`.

Example:

```
<body>
    <div id="start">
        <span class="a">
    </div>
    <div class="a">
    </div>
</body>
```

Start searching for class `a` from the node `<div id="start">` will give you one element,
While if you would have start from the top node- document, it would have ended with two elements.

**Regarding to the `typeof` comparing:**

```
typeof 1 == typeof 2 == "Number" // true
1 !== 2 // true.
```

`typeof` only checks for the type, not the value, `document` and `document.body` are both objects, but different objects.

```
typeof document === typeof document.body === typeof null === "object" // true
document === document.body // false!!!
```

As you can see, `null` and `document` share the same type, but do they have the same methods...? **NO**

Answer (score 4):

Ids are unique to the entire document, therefore it makes no sense to scope them to children nodes of the document.

Class names are not unique and there are use cases that make sense to find elements that have classnames below another element.

`body.getElementsByClassName('foo')` will get the elements that have classname 'foo' but are contained within the body.

`document.getElementsByClassName('foo')` will get all elements with classname 'foo' in the entire document, including the `<head>`.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof document` and `typeof document.body` are the same because they're both `object`.  Types don't work the way you think they do in JS with regard to objects.  So no, they're not the same, and there's no particular reason they would have to support the same function set.  (Even objects with the same prototype don't have to support the same function set, but that's another matter.)  Just call `getElementById` on `document` and it will work.

("Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I hold my arm over my head and rotate it rapidly through a figure-8 pattern!"  "Yeah?  So knock it off.")

Answer (score 0):

Your `typeof` example is not comparing that they are the same thing but that they are the same 'type', for which both return `object`:

Output from Firebug console:

```
>>> typeof document
"object"
>>> typeof document.body
"object"
```

Further details on `typeof` can be found at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof